# scala null point exception while creating a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, orc

I'm trying to read files from a location and load it into a spark dataframe. The below code works correctly:

```
 val tempDF:DataFrame=spark.read.orc(targetDirectory)
```

When I try to provide the schema for the same, the code fails with the issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, brdn6136.target.com, executor 25): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnVector.getDouble(OrcColumnVector.java:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Below is the code I used:

```
val schema = StructType(
      List(
        StructField("Col1",DoubleType,true),
        StructField("Col2",StringType,true),
        StructField("Col3",DoubleType,true),
        StructField("Col4",DoubleType,true),
        StructField("Col5",DoubleType,true),
        StructField("Col6",StringType,true),
        StructField("Col7",StringType,true),
        StructField("Col8",StringType,true),
        StructField("Col9",StringType,true),
        StructField("Col10",StringType,true),
        StructField("Col11",StringType,true),
        StructField("Col12",StringType,true)
      )
    )
val df:DataFrame=spark.read.format("orc")
        .schema(schema)
      .load(targetReadDirectory)
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue ?

Comment: Do you have null value in a double column?

Comment: @Lamanus thank you for the response. Yes, I do have NULLs in the Double column.
Do you think that is causing the issue..?

Comment: Yes, I think. The last error says `OrcColumnVector.getDouble(OrcColumnVector.java:152)` so I suspect that.

Comment: Thanks, @Lamanus. I have used coalesce function to replace NULLs when the folder at the external location is loaded. I will re-run my code.

Comment: @Lamanus, coalesce function didn't seem to work:

```
+ " ,coalesce(Col2,'') as Col2"
```
Can you please suggest any other method to fix this?

Comment: Maybe your schema is different with the original?

Comment: How were these files created? Can you try disabling vectorization https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-orc.html.

Comment: Your coalesce tries to replace null values by what? empty string? it's unsuitable for double as well. Do you have an acceptable dummy value, like 0.0 or -1.0 or smth. OTOH, it seems you've defined your Double column as nullable so I am not sure why it should throw an exception

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov, I did make the default value to be -9999 for double. I still get the same issue.

Comment: @mazaneicha, I will try the method you have suggested.

Comment: @mazaneicha the method you suggested worked!! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Cool. Still you may want to check the origin of those files to see if it can produce native format, which would be more efficient for querying.